# PHP session variable does not survive

Tags: php, forms, session, token

Pretty simple setup: When the page is loading, a random session token is generated and saved in $_SESSION["token"]. A Form contains this token in a hidden input field. No problems until this point. I submit the form to the very same page (action="") and then I try to check if the $_SESSION["token"] is equal to the token that has been sent via POST. A variable is changed accordingly, and then I generate a new session token that replaces the old $_SESSION["token"] before the page loads again.

**Problem is**: The $_SESSION["token"] is changed again the moment the page is called (Before I can compare both SESSION and POST tokens) Therefore, both tokens never match. And I can't figure out WHY it changes. It's not the lines of code I wrote, because these are executed aswell, replacing the random token of unknown origin once again, before the page loads.

INDEX:

```
<?php
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");

$BASE_URL = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$form_valid = false;


if (isset($_POST["token"]) && isset($_SESSION["token"])) {
    if ($_POST["token"] == $_SESSION["token"]) {
        $form_valid = true;
    }
}

//Set (new) session token
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
$_SESSION["token"] = $token;

//Load actual page
include ("/backend/admin.php");
?>
```

INCLUDED PAGE:

```
 <?php echo "FORM VALID:"; var_dump($form_valid); ?> 
 <?php if (!isset($_SESSION["admin"]) || !$_SESSION["admin"]) { ?>

    <form id="verify" method="POST" action="">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="access">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?= $_SESSION['token'] ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Senden">
    </form>

<?php } else { ?>

    ...

<?php } ?>
```

any help is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem in your logic, session token updates every time regardless the form is submitted is not,

```
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
$_SESSION["token"] = $token
```

**Try this,**

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");

    $BASE_URL = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $form_valid = false;


if(empty($_SESSION["token"] )){
 $_SESSION["token"]= bin2hex(random_bytes(10));
}

    if (isset($_POST["token"]) && isset($_SESSION["token"]))
 {
        if ($_POST["token"] == $_SESSION["token"]) {
            $form_valid = true;
            unset($_SESSION["token"]);
        }
    }





    include ("/backend/admin.php");
    ?>
```

Comment: Okay so I tried this and it worked -somehow-. Saying that because while it does solve the problem, it leaves the user unable to type a wrong password and then simply try again. Because no matter what the password is, the token gets unset, and I would have to reload again to get a new token. 
Ah in my example above I cut the part where I actually check for the correct password, sorry. [1/2]

Comment: I still, however, don't see why my logic is flawed. Getting a new token everytime you load the page should be absolutly okay, as long as the new token is set AFTER the existing one was compared or whatever. And that's exactly what I am doing, isn't it?
And when it's just a page-reload -> who cares? No tokens compared and you get a new one. I can't see where this is flawed.

But if it is, please, enlighten me :/ [2/2]

Comment: the problem was 

$_POST["token"] -> old token ,

$_SESSION["token"] -> new token ,

because as soon the user hits submit the page will be refreshed and SESSION will be updated again , leaving POST to have old token . Hope this helps

Comment: But I compare both **before** the $_SESSION["token"] is updated/replaced. Page loads -> Comparison -> new token. Are you telling me the code is not executed in the order that it's written down?

Comment: Try removing hidden from token input field, and echo SESSION['token'] separately , you will get an idea of the flow .

Comment: Did that, and I did a ton of debugging before posting here, believe me. There's a mistake in my thinking of how this works but I can't figure it out. And this thinking is no matter how often I reload the page, the SESSION parameters don't change unless I actively alter them in the code.
That's why I don't get why, after the page is loaded with a certain token, said token is magically replaced **right after** "session_start()" next pageload, when the part where I do replace it is a few lines below (where it then get's replaced once more)
Because submitting the form means 1 reload, right?

Comment: This is all what I can tell you , Sorry if I am not being helpful.